# Intelij Ultimate 2021.2 : import class in grey

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm stuck with the following issue :

I need to import a custom class called "fr.sigma.eaiPublishQueue" in order to run a project developed by a peer.

I don't know why, it's greyed out despite being present in the project's tree and one of its methods being called by the main class.

After multiple reload or rebuilding project or even clone again the repo, issue remains.

[image][image]

Comment: "one of its method being called by the main class." -> can you show that code?

Comment: If it's grey, then IntelliJ considers it unused. You need to provide a [mre].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears the `WatchFolder` class is located in the same package as the `PublishQueue` class. This means that `PublishQueue` does not need to be imported into the `WatchFolder` class because it is already available. IntelliJ IDEA is alerting you to this fact by greying the `import` statement out. Hovering the mouse cursor over the `import` statement should show a warning as well.

Comment: Many thanks for your anwser ! It makes sense indeed.

Answer (score 0):

I do apologize for my answer's delay. I imported manually my project libs (non maven) and it finally ran fine.

Thank you again for your kind help !